# Issue with Angular CLI

Tags: angular

While installing angular CLI on Red hat linux I'm getting below errors. Though I can see ng -v output. But due to below error I'm not able to do the ng build or ng serve.

```
**[root@VMEEPADV07 /]# npm install -g @angular/cli  --force**
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
/usr/bin/ng -> /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

    enter code here

> fsevents@1.2.4 install /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:573
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents/install'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:719:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:228:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:576:3)

> @angular/cli@6.0.1 postinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/ng-update-message.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:573
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng-update-message.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:719:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:228:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:576:3)
+ @angular/cli@6.0.1
added 320 packages from 209 contributors in 10.148s
```

Comment: Which node (version) are u using?

Comment: try running `npm cache clean --force` 
Otherwise `rm -rf node_modules/` and then `npm install`

Comment: Node Version
v10.1.0
NPM Version
6.0.1

Comment: Tried this but showing the same error. This problem dosen't comes on windows

Comment: Interesting thing is this file "/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng-update-message.js" is already there

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, and this is the solution that seemed to work:

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli --unsafe-perm=true
```

- see: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10728

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to change file permissions.